# Mail information to given email on button click HTML

Tags: html, email, button

I have this contact form where the user can put some information in.
When they press 'send' a mail must be send to the given adress 'example@email.com'
with the information in the form.

**Current code:**

```
<div class="contact-form-container">
                        <form id="contact-form" action="mailto:DOESNT WORK!" method="post" class="clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 element-from-left">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="ccr_name" name="ccr_name" required placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 element-from-right">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="ccr_youtube" name="ccr_youtube" required placeholder="Youtube Channel">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 element-from-right">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control"  id="ccr_email" name="ccr_email" required placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 element-from-left">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="ccr_subject" name="ccr_subject" required placeholder="Subject">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 element-from-left">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="ccr_message" name="ccr_message" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 element-from-bottom">
                                <button class="btn custom-btn col-xs-12" type="submit" name="ccr_submit">SEND</button></form> <!-- HERE -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

This is what it looks like:
http://gyazo.com/6ee711d3ab5cfc35444b57ecf7bda506

Answer (score 0):

HTML alone is not made for sending the email containing the information. You will be better off using some PHP to handle that. Look into pulling information from the POST array (ex. `$_POST['ccr_name']` will pull the value that was submitted in the name field) and then use the PHP mail function.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp